# Which query would be better query?

Tags: sql, db2

I am applying joins on more than two tables and below is part of where clause.
Out of following two which is better way of writing it and why??

```
where
    d.bu_id     =   'ABC'
and
    hd.bu_id    =   'ABC'
and 
    s.bu_id     =   'ABC'
```

OR

```
where
    d.bu_id     =   'ABC'
and
    hd.bu_id    =   d.bu_id
and 
    s.bu_id     =   d.bu_id
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  Should be pretty easy to test.

Comment: Is bu_id unique in each table ?

Comment: why are these not in the `ON` clause?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution really depends on your expected change patterns.  If all three are the same because they really do refer to the same entity, it seems more likely that they would all change together.  In that case you'd want to go with your second option to keep from repeating yourself.

If they just happen to have the same value, it's more likely that one of them will change independently in the future, so you'll save yourself hassle by keeping it in the first form.

If you're wondering about performance, there isn't much difference, as any query optimizer should be able to figure both of them out.

Comment: Speaking at least on DB2 for i, the SQE optimizer does not care if a predicate is in the WHERE clause or JOIN ON clause.  It will move a predicates wherever it decides will be most efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to declare a variable to hold the `bu_id` you are looking for, then `join` `hd`, `s`, and `d` together on `bu_id`.  This will allow you to change the `bu_id` in just one location should it ever be necessary.  Adding an index on the `bu_id` fields should ensure good performance.

```
DECLARE @bu_id CHAR(3) = 'ABC'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_d d
    INNER JOIN table_hd hd on hd.bu_id = d.bu_id
    INNER JOIN table_s s on s.bu_id = d.bu_id
WHERE
    d.bu_id = @bu_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have a variable that holds bu_id i did not mention it in the question however. I have another question after your answer , what if i dont mention the inner join clause but simply mention the condition on tables as mentioned above?? what difference it would make?

Comment: I believe @couchand is correct, the performance between your examples will be the same.  In addition, the performance between your examples and my example will also be the same. Both ways result in an inner join.  Using the `INNER JOIN` syntax is the ANSI-92 standard and inner joining tables together in the `WHERE` clause with the `=` sign, as in your second example, is the ANSI-89 standard.